# Doctrine DQL adds a select column which leads to only_full_group_by error

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, dql

I have this query, written in DQL:

```
SELECT
    p
FROM
    Plan p
LEFT JOIN
    p.requests r
WHERE
    p.endsAt > :now
    AND p.organization = :organization
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN r.isAccepted IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE r.isAccepted END) = 0
ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

Which is bound to a paginator.
When iterating on the paginator, I have the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #16
> of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated
> column 'o1_.is_accepted' which is not functionally
> dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
> sql_mode=only_full_group_by").

It's due to Doctrine adding a column (`o1_.is_accepted AS is_accepted_15`) when generating the SQL query, in the select clause (simplified without the `COUNT` operation of the paginator):

```
SELECT o0_.id AS id_0, o0_.average_hourly_rate AS average_hourly_rate_1, o0_.teacher_to_contact_count AS teacher_to_contact_count_2, o0_.starts_at AS starts_at_3, o0_.ends_at AS ends_at_4, o0_.reference AS reference_5, o0_.bac_plus3 AS bac_plus3_6, o0_.created_at AS created_at_7, o0_.is_paid AS is_paid_8, o0_.paid_at AS paid_at_9, o0_.teacher_who_accepted_count AS teacher_who_accepted_count_10, o0_.unit_price_excluding_vat AS unit_price_excluding_vat_11, o0_.billed_amount AS billed_amount_12, o0_.description AS description_13, min(o1_.is_accepted) AS sclr_14, o1_.is_accepted AS is_accepted_15
FROM organization_teacher_request_plan o0_
LEFT JOIN
    organization_teacher_request o1_
    ON o0_.id = o1_.plan_id
WHERE
    o0_.ends_at > ?
    AND o0_.organization_id = ?
GROUP BY o0_.id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN o1_.is_accepted IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE o1_.is_accepted END) = 0
```

It works fine without the sql mode "only_full_group_by". But I want to fix this query as a best practice for migrating to MySQL 5.7.

Adding `MIN(r.isAccepted)` does not work since the `o1_.is_accepted` field in added anyway.

**EDIT:**  it's the `HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN r.isAccepted IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE r.isAccepted END) = 0` part of the DQL query which adds the corresponding field in the select clause, a doctrine bug?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know DQL and have never worked with it, but the syntax looks fairly similar to HQL, and `SELECT p` probably is returning the entire `Plan` entity, including all columns, some of which don't appear in your `GROUP BY` clause.  If you were to select only `p.id`, then the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` error would go away:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM Plan p
LEFT JOIN p.requests r
...
```

Comment: I need the whole Plan entity as a result, and the error is related to the `o1_.is_accepted` field, which is external of my Plan entity.

Comment: You _can't_ use your current query to get the whole plan back, it isn't valid MySQL in the mode your server is using.  You'll have to join again to the main table.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem with this query is the use of the HAVING clause to perform the filter, which then requires the field to be added in the SQL.

A different approach would be using a subquery (with an inverted query and NOT EXISTS clause) to do the same task, which would look like:

```
SELECT
    p
FROM
    Plan p
WHERE
    p.endsAt > :now
    AND p.organization = :organization
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT r.id FROM $FQCN_OF_REQUEST r WHERE r.id MEMBER OF p.requests AND r.isAccepted = 1)
ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

More info: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples